Confusion regarding domain of covariant derivative acting on section of a vector bundle
I am reading Chapter 1.7 of "Gauge Field Theory in Natural Geometric Language" by Daniel Canarutto, which describes linear connections on a vector bundle. I am trained as a physicist and I am a pure mathematics enthusiast at best, so please do excuse me for what could be a very silly question.
Let $F$ be a fibred manifold over base manifold $B$. In chapter 1.6, a connection is defined as a section $\kappa:F \rightarrow \mathrm{J}^{1}F$ with
$$\mathfrak{h} \circ \kappa:F\rightarrow \mathrm{T}^{*}B\otimes_{F}\mathrm{T}F \subset \mathrm{T}^{*}F\otimes_{F}\mathrm{T}F$$
for $\mathrm{J}^{1}F$ the first jet prolongation of $F$ and $\mathfrak{h}:\mathrm{J}^{1}F \hookrightarrow \mathrm{T}^{*}B\otimes_{F}\mathrm{T}F$. Additionally, the "vertical projection $\mathfrak{v}_{\kappa}$ associated with $\kappa$" is defined as a map
$$\mathfrak{v}_{\kappa} \equiv \mathfrak{v}\circ\kappa : F \rightarrow \mathrm{T}^{*}F\otimes_{F}\mathrm{V}F$$
with $\mathrm{V}F$ the vertical subbundle of $\mathrm{T}F$ and $\mathfrak{v}:\mathrm{J}^{1}F \rightarrow \mathrm{T}^{*}F\otimes_{F}\mathrm{V}F$ the  "vertical projection morphism". Given $\kappa$, the covariant derivative $\nabla[\kappa]$ of a section $s:B \rightarrow F$ is defined in terms of $\mathfrak{v}_{\kappa}$ as a section $\nabla[\kappa]s\equiv \mathrm{T}\imath_{s}\mathfrak{v}_{\kappa}:B\rightarrow\mathrm{T}^{*}B\otimes_{F}\mathrm{V}F$ with $\imath_{s}$ the interior product.
Now take $F$ to be a vector bundle. Then $\mathrm{V}F \cong F \times_{B} F$. Hence,
$$(\mathrm{V}F)_{x}=\mathrm{T}F_{x}=F_{x} \times F_{x}$$
for $F_{x}$ the fibre at any $x\in B$. Next is where my confusion comes in. Canarutto then states that "the covariant derivative of a section $s:B \rightarrow F$ can be regarded as a section $\nabla[\kappa]s:B\rightarrow\mathrm{T}^{*}B\otimes_{B}F$". How does this statement follow from the general definition given in the latter paragraph? Potentially even more naive, why
$$(\nabla[\kappa]s)(B)\subset\mathrm{T}^{*}B\otimes_{B}F$$
and not something like
$$(\nabla[\kappa]s)(B)\subset\mathrm{T}^{*}B\otimes_{B}(F\times_{B}F)\mathrm{?}$$
I understand this in terms of more standard treatments of vector bundles, like that of Paul Renteln's "Analysis, Manifolds, and Forms". But in the general framework that Canarutto is working in, it's not quite clear to me.
